# CDB spits out "loading and unloading NatVis script" messages while starting and quitting

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am using version **10.0.18362.1 64-bit** of Windows debugging tools.

When I start or quit **cdb** debugger, it spits out messages like:

> NatVis script successfully loaded from 'C:\Debugging Tools for Windows 10.0.18362.1 64-bit\Visualizers\Windows.Media.natvis

> NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Debugging Tools for Windows 10.0.18362.1 64-bit\Visualizers\Windows.Media.natvis'"

It does so for each of the natvis files.

I don't want them.
Any idea how to avoid them?

I tried `-kqm` switch but that did not help.

Comment: If you create the reg key:
"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Debug Engine" then set the DWORD ExtensionLibraryEnabled to 0 does that help?

Comment: Will that not load the extension all libraries?